# Pseudo-class :after, doesn't markup in HTML on android 2.3

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using Phonegap 3.3 and Jquery mobile 1.4 for my app.
I have a link that opens a pop and JQM 1.4 displays the background icon thanks to the css pseudo-class `:after`, it works on my desktop browser but I can't see the icon nor the `::after` in the html on Android (Phonegap).

my HTML :

```
<div id="blink">Enter <span> size </span>
    <a href="#popupInfo" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn btn-small-round ui-alt-icon ui-icon-info ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="b" data-position-to="origin">Learn more</a>:
</div>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupInfo" data-theme="b" style="max-width:350px;">
    <p>blabla</p>
</div>
```

my CSS:

```
 #welcome-page #leveldata .ui-alt-icon.ui-icon-info:after, #welcome-page #leveldata .ui-alt-icon .ui-icon-info:after {
    background-image: url("../images/info-custom.svg");
}
```

And the HTML produced by JQM doesn't have the ::after, see screenshot below :

[image]

Can you help ?

Comment: ::after is not the problem. Older versions of Android 2.3.6 and below don't have support for SVG and you probably don't have included png icons used as fall back solution.

Comment: @Gajotres I added a fallback to a png version of the icon. Still doesn't work, but it is weird because I still don't see the ::after in the markup : I am including the image in the question.

Comment: @Gajotres I am not using the fallback `background-image: url("../images/info-custom.png"); background-image: url("../images/info-custom.svg");` but the `::after` is still absent in the markup.

Comment: @Gajotres actually it seems that all the css is messed up on Android 2.3 with JQM 1.4...

Comment: I have the same problem with the pseudo-class `:active:` on buttons, it really seems that pseudo-classes are not supporter in Android 2.3.6 webview.

Comment: sorry I meant `:active`